# Missing methods in HtmlAgilityPack in a Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, html-agility-pack, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

I installed the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) package in the portable project of a Xamarin app, but I found that [`SelectNodes`](http://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes) method of the `HtmlNode` class is missing, so this code doesn't compile:

```
 var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
 htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
 var imgNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")
```

because:

> 'HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'SelectNodes' and no
>   extension method 'SelectNodes' accepting a first argument of type
>   'HtmlNode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

I installed the same package on a console application (targets .NET Framework 4.7.1) and  another cross platform app (targets .NET standard 2.0), they both have this method as expected.

this is the targeting list of the project causing the problem:

[image]

Comment: if you want to parse HTML try using AngleSharp

Comment: Maybe it is not available in `Core 1.0`

Comment: @Jason I'm reading the documentation now, but find some troubles to figure out how to change certain attributes of an element (src attribute of img for example) and returning the modified document, is it possible with AngleSharp?

Comment: just select the element and then do element.SetAttribute, I believe